# Count occurrences in a string

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, char, tuples

I am very new to Haskell and am stuck on a problem. The problem is that i need to make a function that takes in a string and returns a list of tuples. The tuple will consist of (character, the number of times that character has appeared in a string).

So far i have written this.

```
charCountTup :: [Char] -> [(Char,Integer)]
charCountTup xs = map (\ x -> (x, 1)) xs
```

input of the string "Hello" will give me

```
('H',1),('e',1),('l',1),('l',1),('o',1)].
```

what i want is

```
('H',1),('e',1),('l',2),('o',1)]
```

i don't want to worry about uppercase and lowercase for now. Anyone more familiar with haskell that has any ideas on how i can increment my tuples' integer based on if it has appeared more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit clumsy .. it's technically a partial function with 'head' in it, but I don't think 'group' returns and empty string. I was lazy and changed your 'Integer' to 'Int'

```
import Data.List (group, sort)

xs = "hello world"

count :: String -> [(Char,Int)]
count  xs = 
    map (\grp -> (head grp, length grp)) (group $ sort xs)
    
count xs
```

> [(' ',1),('d',1),('e',1),('h',1),('l',3),('o',2),('r',1),('w',1)]

I just realized that you can write it using list comprehensions ..

```
[(head grp, length grp) | grp <- (group $ sort xs)]
```

Comment: Thanks man, this work great! I now know how i can build upon it. Thanks!

Comment: or `count = map (head &&& length) . group . sort`

Comment: You can use [`Data.List.NonEmpty.group`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html#v:group) that encodes the non-emptiness in the type: `.. => f a -> [NonEmpty a]`. That version of [`head`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html#v:head) is not partial